# This terminology was adapted or adopted from?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I have sent out a long manuscript of a scientific paper for review, but throughout the paper I have written:

"This terminology was adopted from [famous paper reference]"

With this sentence, I was trying to express that "a word was borrowed/loaned from another source" i.e., the word is not my original creation/invention.

However, I have also seen "adapted from" being used.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Have you checked the meanings of *adapt* and *adopt* in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just depends on context. For what you mean ‘adopted from’ is correct.

If you want to say you took and idea from somewhere else and made changes to adapt it to a new context, then you could tell people it was ‘adapted from’ (the old context).